# 24 hour "gym" In the city

Tags: business, rental-property, real-estate, rent, fair-housing-acts

Lets say someone opens up a 24 hour "gym" installs security cameras everywhere has a couple of bathrooms but the place is made up mostly of rows and rows of couches and some workout equipment.

People pay like $70 a month to be a part of the gym.

Now half the people start sleeping on the couches overnight.

Does this violate United States housing code laws? Is this "gym" legal? Lets say this is in the state of new york.

Comment: What is the gym owner's intent?

Comment: @Someone to create a gym where people if they are tired can sleep for a bit overnight if they are really tired

Comment: Does he install security cameras in the bathrooms/showers? That would most certainly violate some privacy laws.

Comment: @PMF no in this hypothetical he does not

Comment: I know how I would use it ($70 a month for a place to sleep in New York. That has security cameras to protect my stuff?) Deal of a lifetime right there.... Sounds like a flophouse to me... Will probably look/smell like one to